# MS VSC Flask tutorial cannot debug

Tags: python, debugging, flask, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do a Flask project:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask

Currently, I am stuck at step 7.
I am seeing that the Pause button is there in the debugging toolbar. Does this mean that VCS is still running the command?

When I continue to step 8. I am able to see the output in my browser:
“Hello there, VSCode! It's Saturday, 08 August, 2020 at 23:02:35”

In step 8. It says “The small yellow arrow on the breakpoint indicates that it's the next line of code to run.”.
However, I am not able to see any yellow arrow. Why is that?

As a result, I am not able to proceed to step 9.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Naveen

Comment: Why did I get two downvotes? I explained my problem and researched possible solutions thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this is that we did not pass in this 'name', and the breakpoint cannot be entered without obtaining this value. In step 7 of the tutorial, if we did not use'Ctrl+c' in the console, we have not exited yet. The specific steps are as follows:

1. As in the tutorial, set breakpoints at `@app.route("/hello/<name>")` and `now = datetime.now()`.
2. Then click `F5`, the result is as follows:

   [image]
3. Click'step over' until the URL appears in the console, enter the URL, (Hello, Flask!), don't turn it off.
4. Go back to VSCode and click `F5` again. When the breakpoint is at `@app.route("/hello/<name>")`, enter `/hello/VSCode` in the web address bar just now. click `enter`.

   [image]
5. Now we go back to VScode and click'step over', the breakpoint will enter '`now = datetime.now()`' successfully.

   [image]